# Задача C. Пара чисел

Tags: python, олимпиада

Есть массив a состоящий из n целых чисел. Есть ли в массиве два различных индекса i и j такие,
что ai + aj равна сумме всех остальных чисел массива?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Оставьте ваш пример решение данной, задачи за вас её никто решать не будет

Comment: Задача отличная! Чтобы вам помогли уберите картинку, вставьте условия текстом, добавьте ссылку на проверяющую систему, добавьте ваше решение, опишите что с вашим решением не так.

Comment: ну найти 2 максимума в массиве и сумму всего массива - и проверить

Comment: @tym32167, `[1, 1, 2, 2]` - тут два максимума не сработают. Есть другое решение.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy точно, два указателя тогда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение за `O(n*log(n))` с помощью метода двух указателей:

Для начала найдем сумму массива и положим ее в переменную `s`

Отсортируем массив и ставим левый указатель на левый конец массива, то есть `l  = 0` и правый указатель на правый конец массива, `r = n - 1`.

1. Если `a[l] + a[r] < s / 2`, то `l += 1`.
2. Иначе, если `a[l] + a[r] > s / 2`, то `r -= 1`
3. Иначе, мы нашли пару индексов.

---

Решение с помощью хэш-таблиц за `O(n)` в среднем и `O(n^2)` в худшем:

Аналогично находим сумму `s`.

Запихнем все элементы массива в хэш-таблицу и на каждый ключ будем хранить индекс элемента, а далее начинаем итерироваться исходному массиву. И если существует такое `i`, что существует элемент `hash[s / 2 - a[i]]`, то очевидно решение существует и его будет легко восстановить. Естественно надо будет учесть, как в хэш-таблице разобраться с тем, что мы не можем на каждый ключ хранить несколько индексов (вдруг вышло так, что есть хотя бы 2 одинаковых элемента). Однако проблем с этим не должно быть. Можно сделать проверку `i == hash[s/2 - a[i]]` и ее будет вполне достаточно.

Comment: Хеш таблица может хранить списки индексов.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy может, но как мне изначально показалось необходимости в этом нет, по причине не хотелось перебирать элементы списка, ибо сложность будет линейной. Однако нам и не нужно перебирать все элементы списка, 2 элемента посмотреть будет достаточно, чтобы убедиться, что есть хотя бы два разных индекса